# VSCode Go extension auto-sets *.sum/*.mod ownership to root

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

Usinc the latest VSCode (1.40.1 at the time of the post) with the default Go extension (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.Go) with the default config.

Every time one would work with a Go project, some functionality (VSCode or the Go extension) updates some `go.mod` or `go.sum` files and sets file-ownership to `root:root`. This happens on saving some of the Go source files (which triggers some auto module/sum check or something).

One has to explicitly `chown` the file ownership to `$USER:$USER` all the time.

### Question

Any clues how to make sure the file ownership not getting changed?

### Potential reason

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-go/issues/2730

Comment: Are you by chance running VSC as root?

Comment: The `ps -ef | grep /usr/bin/code` returns `<foo_user>     5838  3767  0 17:43 pts/2    00:00:00 grep --color=auto /usr/bin/code`. Also, this kind of things never happened with any other file formats so far (have been using dozes of different ones).